# Resolve 2 arrays before anything on the page with a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 arrays, `sports` and `leagues` and I want those arrays to become resolve before anything on the page, I will paste all of my code regarding those arrays I just mentioned. I need to do this due to an issue I am having with the Angular filters.

this is my html

```
<div ng-repeat="sport in sportsFilter = (sports | filter:query)">
  <div ng-if="sport.leagues.length">
     <!--first array-->
     {{sport.name}}
  </div>
      <div ng-repeat="league in sport.leagues">
        <!--second array-->
        {{league.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

controller

```
  .controller('SportsController', function($scope, $state, AuthFactory,   
               SportsFactory, Sports) {

    $scope.sports = [];
    $scope.sportPromise = Sports;


    AuthFactory.getCustomer().then(function(customer) {
      $scope.customer = customer;
      SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues(customer).then(function(sports) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        if (sports.length) {

          $scope.sportPromise = Sports;

          $scope.sports = sports;

        }else {
          AuthFactory.logout();
        }
      }, function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
     }
    });

    $scope.isSportShown = function(sport) {
      return $scope.shownSport === sport;
    };

  });
```

and here de app.js so far, I thought with this I was resolving the arrays, actually the must important is the array named `leagues`, but still is giving me troubles

```
.state('app.sports', {
  url:'/sports',
  views:{
    menuContent:{
      templateUrl:'templates/sportsList.html',
      controller:'SportsController',
      resolve: {
        Sports: function(SportsFactory, AuthFactory, $q) {
          var defer = $q.defer();

          AuthFactory.getCustomer().then(function(customer) {
            SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues(customer).then(function(sports) {

              var sportLeagues = _.pluck(sports, 'leagues'),
                  leaguesProperties = _.chain(sportLeagues).flatten().pluck('name').value();

              console.log(leaguesProperties);

              defer.resolve(leaguesProperties);

            });

          });
          return defer.promise;
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**UPDATE:**

the page is loading and I my filter is getting the array `leagues` empty, so is not searching thru to it, so I need that array to load first than the filters.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `resolve the arrays`?...

Comment: the page is loading and I my filter is getting the array ```leagues``` empty, so is not searching thru to it, so I need that array to load first than the filters.

Comment: It's incredibly frustrating to sift through all of your code to find a particular issue. Reducing an example to a minimum (I commented this on at least one of your questions, clearly without any effect) will help not only us, but also you, to understand the principles at work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how this could work at a high-level, including avoiding some mistakes you are making.

Mistakes:

- You don't need to use `$q.defer` when the API you are using is already returning a promise. Just return that promise. What you are doing is called an [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern).
- `resolve` is used when you need to do something (like authentication) before you are hitting a particular state. You are under-using the `resolve` by not resolving the `customer`, and instead doing this in the controller.
- `resolve` property of `$stateProvider` can accept other `resolves` as parameters.

With these out of the way, here's how it could work:

```
.state('app.sports', {
  resolve: {
    customer: function(AuthFactory){
       return AuthFactory.getCustomer();
    },
    sports: function(SportsFactory, customer){
       return SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues(customer);
    },
    leagues: function(sports){
       var leagueProperties;

       // obtain leagueProperties from sports - whatever you do there.

       return leagueProperties;
    }
  }
});
```

Then, in the controller you no longer need `AuthFactory` - you already have `customer`:

```
.controller('SportsController', function($scope, customer, sports, leagues){
   $scope.sports = sports;
})
```

Comment: I would incorporate array notation so it would withstand minification, other than that, great answer!

Comment: how you do that ? @iH8 the New Dev answer is fine but I would like to know your way.

Comment: That was impossible to throw in a comment, so i added an answer for who's interested.

Comment: @iH8, respectfully, I did not want to dilute the principle at play in this answer. I rarely if ever use the explicit annotation in answers unless the question/answer pertains to it.

Comment: @NewDev, i understand, you're absolutely right. Just thought i should mention it, maybe i shouldn't have. Since you were talking about ironing out some mistakes, i see not using proper notation is also as a mistake but suddenly introducing that could indeed overcomplicate the answer.

Comment: I really appreciate both answers, I am very new to Angular and would like to know everything about it, good practices, etc thank you and sorry for the headache I've been giving you

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer, a lot of people are new to X language/framework/technology - that is why SO is a great resource. But to keep it great means that questions need to be carefully constructed, thinking not only about your own issue, but also about future visitors that may have similar problems. Not to mention, that trying to reduce and simplify an example, carefully examining what is relevant or not, would help *you* to understand things better and solve issues on your own.

Answer (score 1):

As per request in the comments of New Dev's answer the same only using array notation so that the code remains minifiable:

```
.state('app.sports', {
    resolve: {
        customer: ['AuthFactory', function(AuthFactory){
            return AuthFactory.getCustomer();
        }],
        sports: ['SportsFactory', 'customer', function(SportsFactory, customer){
            return SportsFactory.getSportsWithLeagues(customer);
        }],
        leagues: ['sports', function(sports){
            var leagueProperties;

            // obtain leagueProperties from sports - whatever you do there.

            return leagueProperties;
        }]
    }
});
```

A little explanation to go with that, when you minify this:

```
function (AuthFactory) {
    return AuthFactory.getCustomer();
}
```

You get something like this:

```
function (_1) {
    return _1.getCustomer();
}
```

Now it will try to inject `_1` which is not defined so the code will fail. Now when you minify this:

```
['AuthFactory', function(AuthFactory){
    return AuthFactory.getCustomer();
}]
```

You'll get this:

```
['AuthFactory', function(_1){
    return _1.getCustomer();
}]
```

And that will keep working because now `_1` is assigned to `AuthFactory` because angular injects the first parameter in the function with the first string in the array.

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di (see: inline array notation)